# Remove Leading Zeros in a nvarchar column in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I remove all leading zeros from a `nvarchar` datatype column in SQL Server?

Example:

```
0000000000245
0000000001270
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an implicit conversion as well -- less typing :-)

```
SELECT '0000000000245' + 0
```

This gets more complicated, however, if this nvarchar doesn't *always* contain numbers (in which case @Tim's answer above would have problems as well.).  So...why is this an nvarchar?  Can you alter the table to make it an integer column instead?

Comment: I will try to convert the datatype to int. It was imported as a fixed width file with left zero filled.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to `int`

```
SELECT CAST('0000000000245' AS int),
       CAST('0000000001270' AS int)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2488/1/0)

But why haven't you used `int` in the first place? Displaying leading zeros is a job for the frontend.

Comment: The column contains 350 records with various numbers of leading zeros. If I use CAST I would have to write it for each record.

Comment: The number of records doesn't matter, just use `SELECT CAST(columnName AS int) AS columnName ...`.

Comment: Thank you again. The CAST worked, but will convert the datatype from nvarchar to int. Ps. Love the demo option. That was cool.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solution works well with MS SQL Server (2008 version) without any problems and keeping the column type.

```
CAST(CAST(nvarcharCOL AS int) AS nvarchar)
```